# How to enable a currently disabled button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an action button in my iOS application (using Swift 3), which I guess is technically a toolbar item.

I presently disable the button in viewWillAppear() with

```
actionButton.isEnabled = false
```

I then try to enable it after an image has been selected:

```
func imagePickerController(_: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    actionButton.isEnabled = true
    print("selected an image in picker")
}
```

And I can see that my print statement occurs as well as the image being selected and activity view controller dismissing, just as expected. HOWEVER, my actionButton stays disabled.

Any ideas why? I'm very new to Swift!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`viewWillAppear()` is called every time, before your view controller loads. When you dismiss your imagePicker, and go back to presenting your original viewController that `viewWillAppear()` would be called again, and it would override your `actionButton.isEnable = true` to being false again. If I were you, I would disable the button in `viewDidLoad()`, which is called only once.

Comment: @AndréSlotta Just a curious thought! Does dismissing imgePicker cause the view to reload, meaning calling viewDidLoad()? I think it happens in segues, every time segue is performed view is loaded again. I think imagePicker won't have that effect, but just wanted to have your opinion on that..

Comment: no. the view does not get reloaded and `viewDidLoad` does not get called on the presenting viewcontroller since it is is still there. it is just covered by the imagepicker. only `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` get called again.

Comment: you're welcome. props to you for the correct solution of the problem ;)

Comment: Moving my disable from viewWillAppear() to viewDidLoad() did the trick! I had no idea that viewWillAppear was called in those cases, thank you!

Comment: @AndréSlotta Thanks for your kind words bro.

Comment: @originUnknown you are welcome buddy.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try to execute the code that changes the UI in the main thread like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    actionButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: This delegate will be called on the main thread anyways, so this is not the answer to that question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OPs problem, and won't do anything to fix it. Vändän Ä Patel's answer is the correct one.

Comment: i totally agree :)